# Stacking DNA and trees?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, software-recommendations, myheritage.com

I would like to combine information from my trees at Ancestry and MyHeritage and my family members' DNA kits. Is there a software program I can download that will let me input everything?

I need the software to show me duplicates, and combine information when one has something the other tree did not.

Most importantly, based on multiple DNA kits entered, the software should be able to map out the relationships for me, and tell me where my matches like 3rd cousins should be or are on the tree, if I have enough kits entered to do this.

Comment: What you are asking for is a program you can dump tree data and DNA results into and then have it magically figure everything out for you. We're not close to that yet.

Answer (score 2):

While not a typical program that you are probably looking for, I understand that [The Next Generation of Genealogy Sitebuilding (TNG)](http://www.tngsitebuilding.com/) allows input of DNA results from any source.

The associated [TNG Wiki](https://tng.lythgoes.net/wiki/index.php?title=Compare_DNA_Test_Results) seems to indicate comparisons are available.

The [TNG Forum](https://tng.community/index.php?/forums/) may be a place to ask for further specifics.